# Galera won`t start

Tags: mysql, errors, galera

MariaDB 10.1. 
I have 3 nodes:

**KVM-1**

```
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.2.68,192.168.2.69"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.67'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-1'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

**KVM-2**

```
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.2.67,192.168.2.69"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.68'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-2'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

**KVM-3**

```
wsrep_on=ON
binlog_format=ROW
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://192.168.2.67,192.168.2.68"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.69'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-3'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

I started mysql on 1st server with key `--wsrep-new-clusterping`, ang get errors like this.

```
 mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/mariadb.service.d
           └─migrated-from-my.cnf-settings.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Вт 2016-03-29 15:52:20 MSK; 6s ago
  Process: 7845 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 7845 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "MariaDB server is down"

мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: at gcomm/src/pc.cpp:connect():162
мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: 2016-03-29 15:52:19 139885098440832 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs_core.cpp:gcs_core_open():208: Failed to open backend connection: -110 (Connection timed out)
мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: 2016-03-29 15:52:19 139885098440832 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs/src/gcs.cpp:gcs_open():1379: Failed to open channel 'galera_cluster' at 'gcomm://192.168.2.68,192.168.2.69': -110 (Connection timed out)
мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: 2016-03-29 15:52:19 139885098440832 [ERROR] WSREP: gcs connect failed: Connection timed out
мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: 2016-03-29 15:52:19 139885098440832 [ERROR] WSREP: wsrep::connect(gcomm://192.168.2.68,192.168.2.69) failed: 7
мар 29 15:52:19 KVM-1 mysqld[7845]: 2016-03-29 15:52:19 139885098440832 [ERROR] Aborting
мар 29 15:52:20 KVM-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
мар 29 15:52:20 KVM-1 systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
мар 29 15:52:20 KVM-1 systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
мар 29 15:52:20 KVM-1 systemd[1]: mariadb.service failed.
```

SElinux disabled, iptables & firewalld stopped. 
Servers are available for each other under ip and hostname.

At MariaDB 10.0 was OK.
Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem Solved.

On main node edit `wsrep_cluster_address` to `gcomm://`

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.67'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-1'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

On the other nodes

```
[mysqld]
bind-address=0.0.0.0

[galera]
wsrep_on=ON
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
binlog_format=ROW
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=2
innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog=1
query_cache_size=0
query_cache_type=0
default_storage_engine=InnoDB
innodb_log_file_size=100M
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=2
wsrep_provider=/usr/lib64/galera/libgalera_smm.so
wsrep_cluster_address="gcomm://IP_ADDR_MAIN_NODE,OTHER_NODES_ADDRS"
wsrep_cluster_name='galera_cluster'
wsrep_node_address='192.168.2.68'
wsrep_node_name='KVM-2'
wsrep_sst_method=rsync
wsrep_sst_auth=repl_user:PASS
```

Check Galera Status:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> SHOW STATUS LIKE 'wsrep%';
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                | Value                                                 |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| wsrep_apply_oooe             | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_apply_oool             | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_apply_window           | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_causal_reads           | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_cert_deps_distance     | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_cert_index_size        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_cert_interval          | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_cluster_conf_id        | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_size           | 3                                                     |
| wsrep_cluster_state_uuid     | 2a4dbc40-f5bd-11e5-b2a9-ded6b93d45c9                  |
| wsrep_cluster_status         | Primary                                               |
| wsrep_commit_oooe            | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_commit_oool            | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_commit_window          | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_connected              | ON                                                    |
| wsrep_evs_delayed            |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_evict_list         |                                                       |
| wsrep_evs_repl_latency       | 0/0/0/0/0                                             |
| wsrep_evs_state              | OPERATIONAL                                           |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused    | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_flow_control_paused_ns | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_flow_control_recv      | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_flow_control_sent      | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_gcomm_uuid             | 2a4cb0c4-f5bd-11e5-bef6-22e5e4b1a794                  |
| wsrep_incoming_addresses     | 192.168.2.67:3306,192.168.2.68:3306,192.168.2.69:3306 |
| wsrep_last_committed         | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_bf_aborts        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_cached_downto    | 18446744073709551615                                  |
| wsrep_local_cert_failures    | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_commits          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_index            | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_max   | 1                                                     |
| wsrep_local_recv_queue_min   | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_replays          | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_avg   | 0.000000                                              |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_max   | 1                                                     |
| wsrep_local_send_queue_min   | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_local_state            | 4                                                     |
| wsrep_local_state_comment    | Synced                                                |
| wsrep_local_state_uuid       | 2a4dbc40-f5bd-11e5-b2a9-ded6b93d45c9                  |
| wsrep_protocol_version       | 7                                                     |
| wsrep_provider_name          | Galera                                                |
| wsrep_provider_vendor        | Codership Oy <info@codership.com>                     |
| wsrep_provider_version       | 25.3.15(r3578)                                        |
| wsrep_ready                  | ON                                                    |
| wsrep_received               | 10                                                    |
| wsrep_received_bytes         | 760                                                   |
| wsrep_repl_data_bytes        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys              | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_keys_bytes        | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_repl_other_bytes       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_replicated             | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_replicated_bytes       | 0                                                     |
| wsrep_thread_count           | 2                                                     |
+------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
57 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```